# How do I import css in css file when i use Spring boot framework with Thymeleaf and the context-path?

Tags: css, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, contextpath

I build an application with spring and thymeleaf.
I import style.css in my HTML.
And I have to import other CSS from that file.
Here is a line from my sytle.css

```
@import url(../../js-plugins/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css);
```

It works when I don't apply the context path. But when I apply it, say I set with /path in application.properties, it doesn't work.

```
server.servlet.context-path=/path
```

How do I resolve this problem? How can I add my context path in my style.css?

Note:
I know I can do it by changing the way I import the bootstrap.min.css. I can import the file in my HTML.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

[image]

if you see this picture you should add style.css and template.html that you are using in thymeleaf should be part of the classpath , that is inside /resources/ folder

and then in the html (template.html)
add this code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=@{classpath:templates/css/style.css} />
```

please see in the image below.

[image]

this will import the css class.